# Where to get started in designing a 3 phase motor circuit

Tags: pcb, motor, ac, three-phase

I am required to design a circuit that requires a 3 phase motor which can be spin at a range of desired speeds and times.

I know this will require:
A 3-phase motor
An inverter to convert single phase to 3 phase
A PCB for login and to receive button signals
Some unit for the power

But I don't really know how to go from here. I studied general engineering so I have general idea of basic electronic concepts but I don't know where to go in terms of knowing what component goes with what and how the connect. Are there any resources for this sort of thing?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you use an inverter and an Eaton Easy PLC instead of reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 3):

Three-phase motor control requires an inverter with circuitry to regulate the voltage in proportion to frequency. In addition, there must be an active current limiter, acceleration and deceleration controls and other features depending on the level of performance that is expected from the motor. The entire motor control package is generally called a variable frequency drive (VFD), motor-drive inverter or something similar. There are lots of them on the market and most of them provide excellent performance. Most also have auxiliary functions and interface capability for a wide range of operator or supervisory control systems.

Forget about designing that kind of equipment from scratch. Concentrate on determining the torque and speed requirements of the motor and the operator or automatic control functions. Search for VFD products and look at the resources that the sellers offer. Determine which sellers have a good reputation and good customer support in your part of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Look for reference designs from the usual suspects who are peddling silicon.

The most expensive parts in an inverter are the MCU or DSP, the gate drivers, the isolators and the output devices (typically IGBTs or MOSFETs). The suppliers of those will be eager to help you if your quantities have many zeros after them, but even if  you don't they may well have something relevant to your particular application on their websites.